# How can I save the $_GET Array in php or save its content for longer time?

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to distinguish between a few different calls on a site.

Case 1.) Visit the page directly and then fill and submit the form
Case 2.) Visit the page after following a special link
Case 3.) Visit the page after following a special link and then submit the form

```
 if (($_POST['gesendet']) && (!$_GET['modifiziere_id'])) { 
 //should be entered only when I submit the form
    ...
 // comes here after following a link and then submiting the form

    } elseif ((!$_POST['gesendet']) && ($_GET['modifiziere_id'])) { 
    //should be entered, when I came to this site following a link
    ...

    } elseif (($_POST['gesendet']) && ($_GET['modifiziere_id'])) { 
    //should be entered, after I came to this site following a link and then submit the form
       ...
    // but it's not.

    } else {
     // should be entered when I load the page directly
    }

    ?>
```

After submiting the following form I want to enter case 1

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
 ....
    <input type="submit" value="Senden" name="gesendet" />
```

And the link for case 2 is this:

```
print '<td><a href="teilnehmer_bearbeiten.php?modifiziere_id='.$id.'">Bearbeiten</a></td>'."\n";
```

After I enter case 2 successfully, I want to save the $_GET Array, so that I can submit the form and enter case 3. Instead I always come to case 1, so the $_GET['modifiziere_id'] is not set anymore. The $_GET['modifiziere_id'] should not be reseted.
How can I reset it? I tried it with a simple boolean, but that didn't work (didn't understand why).

Comment: PHP request are stateless... you don't have to reset anything. Each request will have it's own $_GET variables... all you need to do is remove `modifiziere_id` from the url when submitting the form. This should be enough. (or I didn't get the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the other said, you don't need to explicitly reset the `$_GET` array every time.

The problem you are experiencing is because you aren't passing the `$_GET['modifiziere_id']` variable (if it exists) when then form is submitted.

This logic determines how the script is being accessed (this is only different from your implementation because I use [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/isset) to check if the variable is set, in case the `id` is `0`).

```php
<?php    
if (isset($_POST['gesendet']) && !isset($_GET['modifiziere_id'])) { 
    // Came to site and submitted form.
    // ...
} elseif (!isset($_POST['gesendet']) && isset($_GET['modifiziere_id'])) { 
    // Came to site following the link
    // ...
} elseif (isset($_POST['gesendet']) && isset($_GET['modifiziere_id'])) { 
    // Came to site following the link and submitted the form
    // ...
} else {
    // Came to site directly
    // ...
}
?>
```

Before printing the form, you need to determine where to submit the form to. If `$_GET['modifiziere_id']` was present, you also want it to be in the URL that the form is submitted to. So if they visited via the link, the form `action` should be `teilnehmer_bearbeiten.php`, but if they clicked the link it should be `teilnehmer_bearbeiten.php?modifiziere_id=<id>`. There are many ways of doing this, here are two:

```php
// Build the location where the form will be submitted
$form_action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['modifiziere_id'])) {
    $form_action .= '?modifiziere_id=' . $_GET['modifiziere_id'];
}
```

An easier alternative is to simply pass on exactly was was used to get to the current page:

```php
// Build the location where the form will be submitted
$form_action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Whichever one you chose, you now have enough information to build the form. Be careful with using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` by itself, as [you may be exposed to an injection attack](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html).

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php print htmlentities($form_action) ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Senden" name="gesendet" />
</form>
```

Edit: Update answer to use `isset()`

Answer (score 0):

Each time you load the page, a new $_GET array is created, so you don't need to reset it at all! As long as you remove whatever parameters you don't want from the URL (ex. remove the modifiziere_id) it won't appear in the next $_GET array.